# Download TextFile from internet and load a ListBox with the content

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm downloading a txt file from internet but unfortunately, I can't load my listBox with the content from that file.

That's my code:

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://photo-51.netau.net/changelog");

        using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string line;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null){

                lines.Add(line);
                listBox1.Items.Add(lines);
            }
        }
```

When I run it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first read the full stream content into strContent, thus, when you do reader.ReadLine() there's nothing left to read.

If you remove the "var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();" it will work.

Also a simple way to reduce all the code and make it work is this:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
reader.AddRange(sr.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray()));
```

Comment: Ok, now something happen,an error appears telling that the file has "Invalid Path Characters". Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: 1-If the answer was right accept it. 2-If you have a new error create a new post.